# append to a java script array from a vb.net timer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, vb.net

I am not best java script coder but I am familiar with passing an array to java script from vb.net, but I now have a requirement to append to a java script array from a vb.net where timer updates some asp portions of a page, then I need to display the array with java script.

I am successfully passing the value on the timer tick event, but do not know how to append to the java script array without re-writing it each time.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Look into Timer control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865(v=vs.100).aspx you can pass your JS array in the "Tick" event

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear, I need to append to the java script array, I don't have a problem passing the value.

Comment: While inside of the timer Tick event you can use `ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration(v=vs.110).aspx to register a JS array

Comment: That may be interesting, so maintain the array in VB then just pass it to the script on each tick event?

Comment: If ASP.NET timer control is used then yes, since page posts back on every tick and you need to regenerate the entire array. Another (more complicated) option - is to set a JavaScript timer and on every iteration make an AJAX call to ASPX/VB page to retrieve only values and then push them to existing array